# How can I merge 2 arrays in 1 loop?

Tags: java, arrays

I was told to make

```
void mergeArrays(int[] ar1 , int[] ar2)
```

For an input like this:

```
int[] ar1 = {1,2,3,4}
int[] ar2 = {5,6,7,8}
```

This is my code :

```
 public static void mergeArray(int[] ar1 , int[] ar2)    {
        int[] res = new int[ar1.length+ar2.length];
        int counter = 0;
        for(int a = 0; a<ar1.length; a++)
        {
            res[a] = ar1[a];
            counter++;
        }
        for(int b = 0; b<ar2.length; b++)
        {
            res[counter++] = ar2[b];
        }
        for(int temp = 0; temp<res.length;temp++)
        {
            System.out.print(res[temp]+" ");
        }
```

Output `12345678`.

This is done using 2 loops. Now, how can I do it using a single loop?

Comment: is the size of both arrays same?

Comment: I posted the arrays.. Ar1={1,2,3,4} and ar2={5,6,7,8} so i guess it is the same

Comment: Sure you can, just use one index to access both arrays (end condition would be the max of both lengths) and if their length can be different check `index < length` for each array inside the loop.

Comment: if you are merging, then shouldn't the return type be `int[]`?

Comment: But the function is void. So how you can use return?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do it in one loop,

```
        int len = arr1.length + arr2.length;
        int[] res = new int[len];

        for(int i=0, j=0; i<len; i++) {
            if(i<arr1.length){
                res[i] = arr1[i];
            }else{
                res[i] = arr2[j];
                j++;

            }
        }
```

This will work also, when both arrays are of different length.

Answer (score 1):

#### Different length arrays

```
    int[] result = new int[ar1.length + ar2.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = i < ar1.length ? ar1[i] : ar2[i - ar1.length]; // comparison
    }
```

#### Equal length arrays

```
    int[] result = new int[ar1.length + ar2.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
        result[i] = ar1[i];              // no
        result[ar1.length + i] = ar2[i]; // comparison      
    }
```

See (and execute) the full implementation [here](http://tpcg.io/J0IYV6).

Comment: I tried like that (Equal arryas) java keep giving me an error . Can you please edit to full code? With the void main please? Ill try to debug it and see what your full code doing and how its working

Comment: Hi Melkweg! I added a link to the full implementation at the end of my answer.